# Google analytics - difference between analytics data and the data from the core platform

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

We use Google analytics with Google Tag manager for our ecommerce platform based to track the conversion, etc.,
In the thank you page, its used to track the order value and the revenues.

**Consistently we see a difference of about 15 to 20 % difference between GA data and the data from the core platform.**

Tried to find a pattern among the missed orders but couldn´t ascertain one easily. The GA recorded orders include devices like Desktop, tablet and mobile and we see different browsers too.

Need inputs to analyze this better.

*Note: Thank you page is loaded by a redirect from the payment gateway system*

Comment: Inconsistency between tracking solutions is very well documented and can be easily researched. There are numerous reasons for it and I would suggest you analyse your data first and try to find where the problem occurs…

Comment: This was researched based on the inputs from google product forums and other few blogs and the numbers have reduced but still needs some tuning. Ad blocks and JS loading issues are mentioned but no proper inputs available, so trying to leverage the SO community

Answer (score 2):

15-20% difference is not good at all.  Google says you should expect better than 95% accuracy, and to keep at it if you're not getting those numbers.

Note: The more "techy" crowd that your website has, the more folks you'll run into "Do not track" or with Ad-Blocking tech in their browser.  Normally, you'd want to try to baseline that difference using device category filters to see if the gap is bigger for desktop (most phones/tablets don't use ad-blocking).

First, question. If the user lands on the thankyou page, and hits the refresh button,  does it send another "conversion" to GA?  IF so, you want to make sure that you build in logic that prevents duplicate conversions to be sent if the user was not making duplicate purchases. A browser refresh is not a purchase, don't record it as such.

Second, if the page takes forever to load, or you have users that have bad internet, then that could increase the difference. They might be closing the browser or exiting site before GA client has a chance to send the final conversion to the server.  So how is the performance of your thankyou page?

Are you sure you're looking at the correct business data? I've been told GA numbers are off by the business before and it turned out they messed up their own query in the transaction system (and they had been doing so for years!). It is a long shot,  but if you feel super confident about your GA measurement setup, then run it by the folks giving you the transaction numbers.

Finally, if you can't get the difference down then move to the Measurement Protocol server-side implementation of GA.  You simply need to record the IP address of the user and their GA client id, and then construct an HTTPS GET request using the Measurement Protocol fields for a valid hit. Server side measurement is the most accurate way to do this, but requires code updates in the ecommerce platform itself.

Comment: Thanks @pat-grady for your response.